# Streaming Video Chunks Continuosly in JavaFX Media Player

Tags: java, javafx, video-streaming

I have video chunks obtained from queue as byte arrays. I need to play these video chunks on media player like single video without recombining them. Also when new chunks come from queue i need to send them video player.Can I achieve this task by using MediaPlayer or any other solution does exist?

Comment: Manually downloading the bytes and playing them is not possible with `MediaPlayer`. That said, the JavaFX Media API [does support _HTTP Live Streaming_](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedProtocols).

Comment: Then i have to continue with files..Thank you for your advice

Comment: The problem is `javafx.scene.media.*` is a high-level API that provides basically no access to the low-level details of playing media. You simply specify a source of media (in one of a few supported formats) and then the API handles playing it for you, only allowing you to control certain attributes such as volume and rate. You might be able to do what you want with the [Java Sound API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html), but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Although, if you're playing video then the Java Sound API is probably a no-go. Maybe https://github.com/caprica/vlcj can provide what you need, but again I don't have experience with it.

Comment: Actually firstly i tried video streaming to web browser. However when making a request i am able to send only one byte array. "multipart/x-mixed-replace" content-type is only working with jpeg images not suitable for video/mp4. Then i decide to use javafx media. But as i see this is not a good choice also.Again thanks for helping.